# How do i show grand total in pdf packing slip in magento?

Tags: php, magento

We have created a partial invoice and shipment for a order. So my question is how do i show the grand total on pdf packing slip for that perticular partial shipment of order nor order grand total??

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did it some while ago by implementing this code in `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Shipment.php` in the `getPdf()`-function:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($shipment->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(!$item->getOrderItem()->getData('qty_shipped') >= (float)1.0000) {                   
                    continue;
                }
                $total += ($item->getPrice() - $item->getOrderItem()->getDiscountAmount())*$item->getQty();
        }
```

Hope I could help. Regarding your question: The next time you ask something and expect the community to help you, post some code examples, explain what you've tried and why/how it failed, and be a little more precise where in magento's code structure you#re trying to accomplish your goal.

By the way, there's also a Magento-Stackexchange-Site:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/